# how to import packages and some custom setting professionally in python?

Tags: python, list, logging, python-import

I'm using logging packages with some custom setting and I have multiple directory, sub-directory and file So I'm coping and pasting logging setting in every file, this seems unprofessional. like

I'm doing in every file:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO,datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

I want to put this in thing like `utils.py` file So I only import function from utils and start work.

What I try to do, file-name: `utils.py`

```
def logger():
    import logging
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                        level=logging.INFO,
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Importing in some other file and seem it's not working,file-name: `database_service.py`

```
from src.utils import logger as logging
def connection_creator():
    try:
        client = MongoClient(DB_MACHINE, DB_PORT, serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000)
        status = client.server_info()['ok']
        logging.info(f'Connection created Successfully! ["Status":{status}] `localhost` Port: `27017`')
        db_connection = client['techexpert']
        return db_connection
    except Exception as error:
        logging.error(f'in Creating connection `localhost` Port: `27017`! {error}')

db_connection = connection_creator()
```

**Here logging.info() in unresolved reference So what could be best professional way to import these type of settings.**

Comment: Are you aware that ``logging.basicConfig`` should be called once *per program*, not once per module?

Comment: No I'm not and how to run once and then import